# What is the value of $\frac{x}{\operatorname{sin}x}$ in integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

> What is the value of this integral $$\int \frac{x}{\operatorname{sin}x}\:\:dx$$

I came to this question out of curiosity. I know that the value of $\displaystyle\int \frac{\operatorname{sin}x}{x}=\text{Si}(x)+c$ where $$\operatorname{Si}(x)=-\dfrac{\mathrm{i}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(0,\mathrm{i}x\right)-\mathrm{i}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(0,-\mathrm{i}x\right)}{2}$$
Is there also a special integral for $\displaystyle\int\frac{x}{\operatorname{sin}x}\:\:dx?$

Any help is greatly appreciated$?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is "almost" a standard one.
$$I=\int \frac{x}{\sin(x)}\,dx=2i \int \frac{ x}{e^{i x}-e^{-i x}}\,dx=2 i\int \frac{ x\,e^{i x}}{e^{2i x}-1}\,dx$$ Let $u=i x$
$$I=-2i \int \frac {u\, e^u}{e^{2u}-1}\,du$$ Let $e^u=v$
$$I=-2 i\int\frac{ \log (v)}{v^2-1}\,dv=-2 i\int\frac{ \log (v)}{(v+1)(v-1)}\,dv$$
Partial fraction decomposition
$$I=-i \int \Bigg[\frac {\log(v)}{v-1}-\frac {\log(v)}{v+1}\Bigg]\,dv$$
$$\int \frac {\log(v)}{v+a}\,dv=\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{v}{a}\right)+\log (v) \log \left(\frac{v}{a}+1\right)$$ where appears the polylogarithm function.

Use it twice, go back to x, simplify the logarithms to end with
$$I=i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)-2 x \tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)$$